# issue with dateComponents trying to calculate age in years (swiftUI)

Tags: swift, calendar

I'm getting an error that says "Type 'Set' has no member 'year'" when I try to calculate someone's age based on today's date and their birthday:

```
let birthday = "10/08/1978"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: birthday)
let endDate = Date()

let calendar = Calendar.current
let calcAge = calendar.dateComponents(.year, from: startDate!, to: endDate)
let age = calcAge.year
```

Xcode makes me change `calendar.components` to `calendar.dateComponents`, but then `.year` immediately starts reporting an error. As near as I can tell in the developer documentation, `.year` is a valid thing. But then the URL of the developer documentation says I'm looking at calendar.dateComponents, while the heading on the actual page says calendar.components.  Any ideas here? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an array of DateComponents, so the call will become:

let calcAge = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: startDate!, to: endDate)